# What is the difference between StaticResources and DynamicResources in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, wpf-controls

What is the difference between StaticResources and DynamicResources in WPF?

EDIT :
This code in XAML file :

```
<ComboBox Canvas.Left="14" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
          Canvas.Top="137" Height="33" Name="cmbItem" Width="170"
          SelectionChanged="cmbItem_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>Name</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Age</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

below code is in resource dictionary file

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">

    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}"/>

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF436B13"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dynamic resources are evaluated when you use them. Static resources are evaluated at load time.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx#staticdynamic):

> When you use a markup extension, you
>   typically provide one or more
>   parameters in string form that are
>   processed by that particular markup
>   extension, rather than being evaluated
>   in the context of the property being
>   set. The StaticResource Markup
>   Extension processes a key by looking
>   up the value for that key in all
>   available resource dictionaries. This
>   happens during loading, which is the
>   point in time when the loading process
>   needs to assign the property value
>   that takes the static resource
>   reference. The DynamicResource Markup
>   Extension instead processes a key by
>   creating an expression, and that
>   expression remains unevaluated until
>   the application is actually run, at
>   which time the expression is evaluated
>   and provides a value.

There's a lot more detail there about when you should choose which option.

Comment: i am getting this error

"Cannot find resource named '{ComboBoxFocusVisual}'. Resource names are case sensitive.  Error at object 'cmbItem' in markup file"

please suggest a solution..

Comment: This code in XAML file
<ComboBox  Canvas.Left="14" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" Canvas.Top="137" Height="33" Name="cmbItem" Width="170" SelectionChanged="cmbItem_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem>Name</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Age</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>

below code is in resource dictionary file

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}"/>

Comment: I added the code to the original post so that it's easier to read... But I don't see "ComboBoxFocusVisual" anywhere in that code

Comment: ResourceDictionary code is as..where is that original post?

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}">
</Style>

Answer (score 2):

From your comment below Jon's answer :

> i am getting this error "Cannot find resource named '{ComboBoxFocusVisual}'. Resource names are case sensitive. Error at object 'cmbItem' in markup file"

I think your ComboBoxFocusVisual resource is declared after ComboBoxStyle, so the `StaticResource` extension can't find it. You should either declare it before you reference it, or reference it with a `DynamicResource` extension

Comment: I've already seen the edited post, and my answer remains the same... I told you what to change. Is there something you don't understand ?